# Should my open source CMS support multiple database platforms?

Tags: database, open-source, content-management-system

I am developing an open source CMS and have been deciding whether or not to offer support for multiple database platforms. What are your views and opinions on this matter? Should I stick with and optimize for a single platform or offer support for more?

Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT depends on your plans. If you want the CMS to became popular  (I meant Open Source) make it as flexible as possible with high database abstraction. I can only tell that leading PHP - based CMS "Drupal"  went through path form MySQL only to all leading DBs including NoSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Ceirtainly, it should. At least, it should be scalable and customizable, that's why uses may prefer different databases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more users, then yes. Some of your users might like Microsoft SQL Server. Others might find that Oracle's fathering of MySQL put other open source databases into higher regard. Same principle applies to what webservers (IIS, Apache) and web browsers you support. (IE, FireFox, Safari, Chrome, etc.)